Why is it impossible to deploy a program to mainnet?
Just want to preface this by saying that I never have joined a stack exchange in my 10+ years of engineering to get a question answered.
I’ve already combed through all the posts on here regarding this.
Why can’t I deploy to mainnet? What is the trick? What is the secret I’m missing? Transaction times out no matter what RPC I use, no matter what flags, or options. Doesn’t matter if I try it at 3am or 3pm, it always times out.
Please help me understand what I’m doing wrong. Why is it so hard to deploy to mainnet? I tried downgrading to v1.14.18 but still nothing..

could you share what you've tried so far? I wouldn't also recommend on downgrading you cli suite. Check out this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/13690/1708.

This question is similar to: Mainnet contract deployment hangs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version of Solana with the retries and priority fee flags available.
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/your_program.so  --with-compute-unit-price 5000 --use-rpc  --max-sign-attempts 200

It takes a bit (and sometimes some retries), but this is what I've found works for me.
